# Obrigar o preenchimento do input com um ponto em vez de virgula em html

Tags: php, javascript, html

Na tabela o campo preço tem o tipo de dados Decimal, onde o `input` está desta forma:

```html
<p><h5><strong>Preço</strong></h5> <input type="text" id="Preco" name="Preco" size="120" /><br/></p>
```

Mas eu dar entrada do produto e do preço, se colocar o valor com vírgula não insere na base de dados.

Pretendo obrigar o preenchimento com o ponto, se colocar a vírgula dar uma mensagem avisar que tem de usar o ponto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha, se você está trabalhando com centavos, pode usar `JQuery` com esse sistema:

**[JQuery Mask Money](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney)**

Inclua os dois *.JS no cabeçalho do `HTML`, depois crie a função que vai checar, ele não só vai impedir que use virgula, como vai inserir o ponto automaticamente.

O usuário só vai ter que digitar números sem ter que se preocupar em apertar outro botão.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#Preco').maskMoney({ decimal: '.', thousands: '', precision: 2 });
})
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="Preco" value="0.00" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Não é de boas práticas restringir o utilizador.

Deixe ele colocar o que quiser e faça você essa validação:

```
<input input type="text" id="Preco" name="Preco" size="120" onchange="this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '.')"/>
```

Comment: Obrigado....Funcionou

Answer (score 1):

Tenho uma solução simples pra você amigo, não se limite ao ponto ou virgula, você deve pensar na experiência do usuário com a sua plataforma. Existe uma `lib` chamada [mask js](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/), ela serve pra criar mascaras no seu `input` e deixa-lo com uma formatação mais amigável. A unica coisa que você precisa fazer é importa ela e o `jquery` antes dela. A utilização é básica.

Para implementação você tem duas opções, `data-attribute` do html, ou no `js` mesmo.

```
// html    
<input type="text" name="preco" data-mask="#.##0,00" />

// js        
$('input[name='preco']').mask("#.##0,00", {
        reverse: true
      });
```

Usando isto o seu campo preço terá uma formatação de dinheiro amigável ao usuário. Mas o formato será inválido para salvar no banco, para solucionar esse problema, vou disponibilizar uma `function` pra você, que converte esse preço com essa formatação para salvar no banco, e vice-versa.

```
function formattedPriceForDB($price) { // formata pra salvar no banco
    $source = array('.', ',');
    $replace = array('', '.');
    $valor = str_replace($source, $replace, $price); //remove os pontos e substitui a virgula pelo ponto
    return $valor; //retorna o valor formatado para gravar no banco
}

function formattedPrinceForBr($price) { // formata pra mostrar ao usuário
        return number_format($price, 2, ',', '.');
    }
```

Caso prefira receber só pontos utilize esse código:

```js
$("form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if($("#preco").val().indexOf(",") != -1){
    $("span").text("erro ! retire as virgulas e coloque pontos");
  } else {
    $("span").text("tudo certo");
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<input type="text" name="preco" id="preco"/> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="enviar"/>
<span></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa script com `jQuery` faz o que você está pedindo:

```js
$(document).on("keyup", '.preco', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 188 || e.keyCode == 108) { // KeyCode For comma is 188
        alert('Use ponto');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><h5><strong>Preço</strong></h5> <input type="text" id="Preco" class="preco" name="Preco" size="120" /><br/></p>
```

Agora se você deseja algo mais avançado olhe abaixo:

```js
/*
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2006-2011 Sam Collett (http://www.texotela.co.uk)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 * and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.
 * 
 * Version 1.3.1
 * Demo: http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/
 *
 */
(function($) {
/*
 * Allows only valid characters to be entered into input boxes.
 * Note: fixes value when pasting via Ctrl+V, but not when using the mouse to paste
  *      side-effect: Ctrl+A does not work, though you can still use the mouse to select (or double-click to select all)
 *
 * @name     numeric
 * @param    config      { decimal : "." , negative : true }
 * @param    callback     A function that runs if the number is not valid (fires onblur)
 * @author   Sam Collett (http://www.texotela.co.uk)
 * @example  $(".numeric").numeric();
 * @example  $(".numeric").numeric(","); // use , as separator
 * @example  $(".numeric").numeric({ decimal : "," }); // use , as separator
 * @example  $(".numeric").numeric({ negative : false }); // do not allow negative values
 * @example  $(".numeric").numeric(null, callback); // use default values, pass on the 'callback' function
 * @example  $(".numeric").numeric({ scale: 2 }); // allow only two numbers after the decimal point.
 * @example  $(".numeric").numeric({ scale: 0 }); // Same as $(".numeric").numeric({ decimal : false });
 * @example  $(".numeric").numeric({ precision: 2 }); // allow only two numbers.
 * @example  $(".numeric").numeric({ precision: 4, scale: 2 }); // allow four numbers with two decimals. (99.99)
 *
 */
$.fn.numeric = function(config, callback)
{
 if(typeof config === 'boolean')
 {
  config = { decimal: config };
 }
 config = config || {};
 // if config.negative undefined, set to true (default is to allow negative numbers)
 if(typeof config.negative == "undefined") { config.negative = true; }
 // set decimal point
 var decimal = (config.decimal === false) ? "" : config.decimal || ".";
 // allow negatives
 var negative = (config.negative === true) ? true : false;
 // callback function
 callback = (typeof(callback) == "function" ? callback : function() {});
 // scale
 var scale;
 if ((typeof config.scale) == "number")
 {
  if (config.scale == 0)
  {
   decimal = false;
   scale = -1;
  }
  else
   scale = config.scale;
 }
 else
  scale = -1;
 // precision
 var precision;
 if ((typeof config.precision) == "number")
 {
  precision = config.precision;
 }
 else
  precision = 0;
 // set data and methods
 return this.data("numeric.decimal", decimal).data("numeric.negative", negative).data("numeric.callback", callback).data("numeric.scale", scale).data("numeric.precision", precision).keypress($.fn.numeric.keypress).keyup($.fn.numeric.keyup).blur($.fn.numeric.blur);
};

$.fn.numeric.keypress = function(e)
{
 // get decimal character and determine if negatives are allowed
 var decimal = $.data(this, "numeric.decimal");
 var negative = $.data(this, "numeric.negative");
 // get the key that was pressed
 var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
 // allow enter/return key (only when in an input box)
 if(key == 13 && this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "input")
 {
  return true;
 }
 else if(key == 13)
 {
  return false;
 }
 var allow = false;
 // allow Ctrl+A
 if((e.ctrlKey && key == 97 /* firefox */) || (e.ctrlKey && key == 65) /* opera */) { return true; }
 // allow Ctrl+X (cut)
 if((e.ctrlKey && key == 120 /* firefox */) || (e.ctrlKey && key == 88) /* opera */) { return true; }
 // allow Ctrl+C (copy)
 if((e.ctrlKey && key == 99 /* firefox */) || (e.ctrlKey && key == 67) /* opera */) { return true; }
 // allow Ctrl+Z (undo)
 if((e.ctrlKey && key == 122 /* firefox */) || (e.ctrlKey && key == 90) /* opera */) { return true; }
 // allow or deny Ctrl+V (paste), Shift+Ins
 if((e.ctrlKey && key == 118 /* firefox */) || (e.ctrlKey && key == 86) /* opera */ ||
   (e.shiftKey && key == 45)) { return true; }
 // if a number was not pressed
 if(key < 48 || key > 57)
 {
   var value = $(this).val();
  /* '-' only allowed at start and if negative numbers allowed */
  if(value.indexOf("-") !== 0 && negative && key == 45 && (value.length === 0 || parseInt($.fn.getSelectionStart(this), 10) === 0)) { return true; }
  /* only one decimal separator allowed */
  if(decimal && key == decimal.charCodeAt(0) && value.indexOf(decimal) != -1)
  {
   allow = false;
  }
  // check for other keys that have special purposes
  if(
   key != 8 /* backspace */ &&
   key != 9 /* tab */ &&
   key != 13 /* enter */ &&
   key != 35 /* end */ &&
   key != 36 /* home */ &&
   key != 37 /* left */ &&
   key != 39 /* right */ &&
   key != 46 /* del */
  )
  {
   allow = false;
  }
  else
  {
   // for detecting special keys (listed above)
   // IE does not support 'charCode' and ignores them in keypress anyway
   if(typeof e.charCode != "undefined")
   {
    // special keys have 'keyCode' and 'which' the same (e.g. backspace)
    if(e.keyCode == e.which && e.which !== 0)
    {
     allow = true;
     // . and delete share the same code, don't allow . (will be set to true later if it is the decimal point)
     if(e.which == 46) { allow = false; }
    }
    // or keyCode != 0 and 'charCode'/'which' = 0
    else if(e.keyCode !== 0 && e.charCode === 0 && e.which === 0)
    {
     allow = true;
    }
   }
  }
  // if key pressed is the decimal and it is not already in the field
  if(decimal && key == decimal.charCodeAt(0))
  {
   if(value.indexOf(decimal) == -1)
   {
    allow = true;
   }
   else
   {
    allow = false;
   }
  }
 }
 //if a number key was pressed.
 else
 {
  // If scale >= 0, make sure there's only <scale> characters
  // after the decimal point.
  if($.data(this, "numeric.scale") >= 0)
  {
   var decimalPosition = this.value.indexOf(decimal);
   //If there is a decimal.
   if (decimalPosition >= 0)
   {
    decimalsQuantity = this.value.length - decimalPosition - 1;
    //If the cursor is after the decimal.
    if ($.fn.getSelectionStart(this) > decimalPosition)
     allow = decimalsQuantity < $.data(this, "numeric.scale");
    else
    {
     integersQuantity = (this.value.length - 1) - decimalsQuantity;
     //If precision > 0, integers and decimals quantity should not be greater than precision
     if (integersQuantity < ($.data(this, "numeric.precision") - $.data(this, "numeric.scale")))
      allow = true;
     else
      allow = false;
    }
   }
   //If there is no decimal
   else {
    if ($.data(this, "numeric.precision") > 0)
     allow = this.value.replace($.data(this, "numeric.decimal"), "").length < $.data(this, "numeric.precision") - $.data(this, "numeric.scale");
    else
     allow = true;
   }
  }
  else
   // If precision > 0, make sure there's not more digits than precision
   if ($.data(this, "numeric.precision") > 0)
    allow = this.value.replace($.data(this, "numeric.decimal"), "").length < $.data(this, "numeric.precision");
   else
    allow = true;
  }
 return allow;
};

$.fn.numeric.keyup = function(e)
{
 var val = $(this).val();
 if(val && val.length > 0)
 {
  // get carat (cursor) position
  var carat = $.fn.getSelectionStart(this);
  // get decimal character and determine if negatives are allowed
  var decimal = $.data(this, "numeric.decimal");
  var negative = $.data(this, "numeric.negative");
  
  // prepend a 0 if necessary
  if(decimal !== "" && decimal !== null)
  {
   // find decimal point
   var dot = val.indexOf(decimal);
   // if dot at start, add 0 before
   if(dot === 0)
   {
    this.value = "0" + val;
   }
   // if dot at position 1, check if there is a - symbol before it
   if(dot == 1 && val.charAt(0) == "-")
   {
    this.value = "-0" + val.substring(1);
   }
   val = this.value;
  }
  
  // if pasted in, only allow the following characters
  var validChars = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'-',decimal];
  // get length of the value (to loop through)
  var length = val.length;
  // loop backwards (to prevent going out of bounds)
  for(var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
   var ch = val.charAt(i);
   // remove '-' if it is in the wrong place
   if(i !== 0 && ch == "-")
   {
    val = val.substring(0, i) + val.substring(i + 1);
   }
   // remove character if it is at the start, a '-' and negatives aren't allowed
   else if(i === 0 && !negative && ch == "-")
   {
    val = val.substring(1);
   }
   var validChar = false;
   // loop through validChars
   for(var j = 0; j < validChars.length; j++)
   {
    // if it is valid, break out the loop
    if(ch == validChars[j])
    {
     validChar = true;
     break;
    }
   }
   // if not a valid character, or a space, remove
   if(!validChar || ch == " ")
   {
    val = val.substring(0, i) + val.substring(i + 1);
   }
  }
  // remove extra decimal characters
  var firstDecimal = val.indexOf(decimal);
  if(firstDecimal > 0)
  {
   for(var k = length - 1; k > firstDecimal; k--)
   {
    var chch = val.charAt(k);
    // remove decimal character
    if(chch == decimal)
    {
     val = val.substring(0, k) + val.substring(k + 1);
    }
   }
   // remove numbers after the decimal so that scale matches.
   if ($.data(this, "numeric.scale") >= 0)
    val = val.substring(0, firstDecimal+$.data(this, "numeric.scale") + 1);
   // remove numbers so that precision matches.
   if ($.data(this, "numeric.precision") > 0)
    val = val.substring(0, $.data(this, "numeric.precision") + 1);
  }
  // limite the integers quantity, necessary when user delete decimal separator
  else if ($.data(this, "numeric.precision") > 0)
   val = val.substring(0, ($.data(this, "numeric.precision") - $.data(this, "numeric.scale")));
  
  // set the value and prevent the cursor moving to the end
  this.value = val;
  $.fn.setSelection(this, carat);
 }
};

$.fn.numeric.blur = function()
{
 var decimal = $.data(this, "numeric.decimal");
 var callback = $.data(this, "numeric.callback");
 var val = this.value;
 if(val !== "")
 {
  var re = new RegExp("^\\d+$|^\\d*" + decimal + "\\d+$");
  if(!re.exec(val))
  {
   callback.apply(this);
  }
 }
};

$.fn.removeNumeric = function()
{
 return this.data("numeric.decimal", null).data("numeric.negative", null).data("numeric.callback", null).unbind("keypress", $.fn.numeric.keypress).unbind("blur", $.fn.numeric.blur);
};

// Based on code from http://javascript.nwbox.com/cursor_position/ (Diego Perini <dperini@nwbox.com>)
$.fn.getSelectionStart = function(o)
{
 if (o.createTextRange)
 {
  var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
  r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length);
  if (r.text === '') { return o.value.length; }
  return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text);
 } else { return o.selectionStart; }
};

// set the selection, o is the object (input), p is the position ([start, end] or just start)
$.fn.setSelection = function(o, p)
{
 // if p is number, start and end are the same
 if(typeof p == "number") { p = [p, p]; }
 // only set if p is an array of length 2
 if(p && p.constructor == Array && p.length == 2)
 {
  if (o.createTextRange)
  {
   var r = o.createTextRange();
   r.collapse(true);
   r.moveStart('character', p[0]);
   r.moveEnd('character', p[1]);
   r.select();
  }
  else if(o.setSelectionRange)
  {
   o.focus();
   o.setSelectionRange(p[0], p[1]);
  }
 }
};

})(jQuery);

$(".numeric").numeric({ decimal : ".",  negative : false, scale: 3 });

$(document).on("keyup", '.numeric', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 188 || e.keyCode == 108) { // KeyCode For comma is 188
        alert('Use ponto 10.00');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Preço
<input class="numeric" type="text" />
```

Código retirado de: https://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/fhYAs/

Comment: O primeiro exemplo que me colocou, o mais simples, aqui faço executar e funciona, na minha página não aparece a mensagem de colocar o ponto ou de obrigar o usuário a colocar o ponto

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a tag `pattern` do `html`, veja;

```html
<form action="#">
<label for="price">Preço:</label> 
<input type="text" 
        name="price" 
        pattern="[0-9]\.[0-9]"
        title="casa decimal deve ser separada por ponto"
/>
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Veja as versões dos browsers que suportam a tag `pattern`:

- Chrome: 5.0+
- Edge 10.00+
- Firefox: 4.0+
- Safari: 10.1+
- Opera 9.6+

Para mais informações, veja a [pagina da `w3cschool` sobre a tag `pattern`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

Comment: Mas com este exemplo ele não aceita nem vírgulas nem pontos, diz para preencher com o formato pedido

Comment: @Junior desculpe, esqueci de incluir a tag `title`.

Answer (score 0):

Tem várias soluções para seu problema.

- HTML (cuidado, problemas de compatibilidade entre navegadores)

Você pode usar um tipo diferente de input (number em vez de text), assim o usuário não vai poder entrar vírgulas (só pontos). No Mozilla Firefox, o código a seguir basta, no entanto para outros navegadores é possível que tenha que adicionar o atributo `step="any"` para que funcione com números não inteiros.

`<input type="number" id="Preco" name="Preco" size="120" />`

- JavaScript (lado do cliente)

Ou você pode usar Javascript (jQuery aqui) para transformar as vírgulas em pontos, por exemplo:
`$(this).val($(this).val.replace(',', '.'));`

que você pode executar no evento "onchange" por exemplo. Se você preferir deixar essa transformação escondida do usuário, usa essa função só quando o formulário está enviado (evento do submit).

- PHP (lado do servidor)

Ou você pode fazer isso em PHP:

`$preco = $_POST['Preco'];
$preco = str_replace(",", ".", $preco);`

Pode verificar que o valor entrado é um número com essa função (PHP) também:

`if (!is_numeric($preco)) { // tem um erro! }`

---

Vale lembrar que é necessário fazer as verificações no servidor de qualquer maneira, já que o usuário pode modificar o código que está na máquina dele (lado do cliente).

Comment: O `type="number"` nem deixa utilizar vírgula nem pontos, só números inteiros

Comment: Desculpa, eu estou usando Firefox e ele aceita pontos. O Chrome não deixa. Vou editar minha resposta.

Comment: Aparentemente apenas versões anteriores do Chrome não deixavam sem o atributo "step", mas agora já funciona sem nada (desde a versão 43 pelo menos). Teria que pesquisar mais para saber dos outros navegadores. (Imagino que IE tenha suas próprias regras...)

Answer (score 0):

@[Junior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/104114/junior), utilize o `MeioMask` para o front:

https://github.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask

É bem fácil de utilizar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Preco').setMask({
        mask: '99,999.99', type: 'reverse'
    });
});
</script>
```

Nesse JS acima, vc força o usuário a digitar a casa decimal com vírgula e o separador de milhar com ponto.

Aí no PHP vc faz a seguinte limpeza antes de colocar na sua Query:

```
<?php $Preco = $str_replace(array('.',','),array('','.'),$_POST['Preco']); ?>
```